# Does garbage collection happen immediately after Hashmap.remove() is called?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

The Java code is as follows:

```
Random r = new Random(1234697890);
HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<1000;j++){
        list.add(r.nextInt(100000));
    }
    map.put(i, list);
    map.remove(i);
}
```

when `i` reaches 37553 , `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` happens.
It seems that garbage collection does not happen in the loop.
Now I wonder how to fix the problem.

Comment: You're always adding to the list, and never removing from it.

Comment: FYI, guava has a `Multimap` set of classes that implement `Map<K, List<V>>` and takes care of creating the lists for you.

Comment: @JohnB - how is that possibly relevant to the question?

Comment: @Perception that is why I marked it as an FYI. I consider information sharing to be a good thing and the first time someone showed me `Multimap` I was quite grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try rewriting the code as follows and you should not get OOME's ...

```
Random r = new Random(1234697890);
HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();

for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int j=0;j<1000;j++){
        list.add(r.nextInt(100000));
    }
    map.put(i, list);
    map.remove(i);
}
```

The problem with your original code is that:

- you only create one list,
- you keep adding more and more elements to it, and
- that list only becomes garbage when the code completes ... because it is "in scope" the whole time.

Moving the `list` declaration inside the loop means that a new `ArrayList` is created and filled in each loop iteration, and becomes garbage when you start the next iteration.

---

Someone suggested calling `System.gc()`.  It won't help at all in your case because there is minimal<sup>1</sup> garbage to be collected.  And in general it is a bad idea because:

- the GC is guaranteed to have run immediately before an OOME is thrown,
- the JVM can figure out better than you can when is the best (i.e. most efficient) time to run the GC,
- your call to `System.gc()` may be totally ignored anyway.  The JVM can be configured so that calls to `System.gc()` are ignored.

<sub>1 - The pedant in me would like to point out that `map.put(i, list); map.remove(i);` is most likely generating an `Integer` object that most likely becomes garbage.  However, this is "chicken feed" compared to your indefinitely growing `ArrayList` object.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

You use the same List all the time, which contains 100000 * 1000 items when the loop exits. To enable GC to get rid of your list, you need to reduce its scope to within the `for(i)` loop.

In other words, both map and list are reachable at all time in that piece of code and are therefore not eligible for collection.

Comment: Alternatively, you can increase the heap size so that the method is able to finish and everything can be GC'd then :D

Answer (score 0):

In your case you keep filling the same `list` (even though you remove it from that HashMap, it still exists as a local variable).

The JVM promises to do a full garbage collect before throwing an `OutOfMemoryError`. So you can be sure there is nothing left to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<1000;j++){
        list.add(r.nextInt(100000));
    }
    map.put(i, list);
    map.remove(i);
}
```

is the same as

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i=0;i<100000 * 1000; i++) {
    list.add(r.nextInt(100000));
}
```

As you can see its the List, not the map which is retaining all the integers.  BTW Try this instead and see what happens ;)

```
list.add(r.nextInt(128));
```